# Do we consider opinions on which facts have the most weight as "facts" or "opinions"?

Tags: discussion, questions

I am really confused as to how [this question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/15889/why-is-palestine-not-a-state-yet) can be anything but an invitation to opine.

Controversial topics generally have facts supporting both sides of an argument.  A controversy arises out of opinions about which facts should matter (ie, what facts should outweigh the other facts).

The OP, as it was originally posited, was already researched on facts.  Which meant that this question needed either comments outlining which facts were missing from the causes of the conflict or all the causes were listed and the question asked to evaluate which of them outweighed the others.

This is opinion-baiting.  And, given that the answer which was accepted by the OP author was a one-sided answer, it's clear which opinions the OP was looking to elevate.

In what way is such a question not primarily opinion-based?  Since the original question was already researched on facts, was is it a rant disguised as a question?

Answer (score 1):

The question has 8 downvotes and 4 close votes as I write. You can always downvote and close vote such questions.

FWIW, too, the question doesn't seem that well researched on facts - it's literally 3 sentences long and asking basic questions. If there was a "Question is too basic" (as in answerable by wikipedia) close vote option like there is in History I'd have used it on that question. Closing as too broad or primarily opinion based works too.

Comment: look at its history.  all the facts have been removed from the question by its author.